# vim plugin changes rust files to use a ts of 4 rather than 2

Tags: vimrc, indentation, tab-characters

Let's say I have a simple file,

```
echo -n "\tTABBED ONCE" > foo.rs
```

And then I have in my `.vimrc` the following,

```
set ts=2
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
call plug#end()
```

How come I open that file `vim foo.rs` my `ts` is set to `4`?

I may have something else changed somewhere. I just don't know where to look. Does this happen with anyone else?

Comment: Duh. The same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56408989/set-tab-as-2-spaces-in-vimrc-but-still-set-to-4-spaces-when-editing-python-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to add this to my vimrc,

```
let g:rust_recommended_style=0
```

You can see this [mentioned here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust.vim/issues/105) and [implemented here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust.vim/blob/master/ftplugin/rust.vim#L48)